# Missing argument for parameter 'options' in call

Tags: swift

Trying to compile the following code I get the above error:

```
let ref = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
let image = CIImage(CVImageBuffer: ref)
```

Near as I can tell, CIImage has an initializer that takes only a CVImageBuffer (it has another initializer that also takes an options parameter. If I try and provide that, I get an error that I’ve got an *extra* argument called options, blurgh)

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s simple! It turns out the problem was I wasn’t passing the proper *kind* of reference in.

The line `let ref = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)` actually declares `ref` as an `Unmanaged<>` structure value, which means the API hasn’t been properly annotated to indicate what kind of retained/unretained relationship ARC should interpret. It’s basically considered a loose canon.

So what I had to do was explicitly tell the compiler to give me an unretained version, and then the code works great.

```
let ref : CVImageBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer).takeUnretainedValue()
let image = CIImage(CVImageBuffer: ref)
```